CGO and Clang not compiling on Mac for Typedef Enum Struct but working on Linux
I have a typedef enum struct defined as such
typedef enum struct EnumStructName : int { Val1, Val2, Val2 } EnumStructName;

When I am compiling the C++ code on my Mac its working fine. And its creating a proper library (.a) file and all the tests pass.
I then use the library in my Golang Code base using the following flags:
//#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++17
//#cgo CXXFLAGS: -I../lib/inc -I/usr/local/include
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L../lib/build/ -lengine -lstdc++ -lm
//#include <stdbool.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

I get the following error when I try to build with golang using Clang
CC=clang go build gives the following error:
error: expected identifier or '{'
typedef enum struct EnumStructName : int { Val1, Val2, Val2 } EnumStructName;
             ^

The thing is it builds fine on Linux (and on Linux Docker Images) - just not on my Mac. Any idea why this might be the case?

What is the point of typedef? Why not simply write enum class EnumStructName : int { Val1, Val2, Val2 }?

Not sure this is old code from someone I have inherited - before I make changes to the codebase would like to see if I can get it to build - since it does build properly in a docker container (just not on my mac)

The error looks like you are building with C compiler instead of C++ compiler (or pre-C++11 compiler, Apple Clang likes to pull off such tricks). I just tried to simplify the problem, since typedef adds extra layer of unnecessary syntax complexity.

Yes but Golang only allows C and not C++, hence need to use clang and not clang++. It does compile with Clang++ properly on Mac (thats how I build my library). I agree it adds unnecessary layer - but want to try to build as is if I can without making a big change to the codebase (its not just one enum struct - there are 100s)

Well, C has no enum class nor enum struct. You cannot compile that in C.

As Yksisarvinen, said, you need to export C-compatible interface from what you attempt to link to the Go code, and use it.

Yes there is a C compatible interface that is exposed - and its perfectly fine on Linux - its just on mac that it breaks.

«there is a C compatible interface that is exposed» – enum struct (and enum class) do not exist in C, so I fail to see how your statement holds true.
